# I [had]/[have] been in a pretty good mood so far

Tags: grammaticality

CONTEXT:

John to Bob: "I was wondering if you could lend me some money, Bob."

Bob to John: "I've been in a pretty good mood so far, so stop bringing me down with that nonsense."

Chris to Bob: "What did you just say to John?"

Then Bob says to Chris one of the sentences below.

SENTENCES:

1. I told him that I **have been** in a pretty good mood so far, and asked him to stop bringing me down with that nonsense.
2. I told him that I **had been** in a pretty good mood so far, and asked him to stop bringing me down with that nonsense.

QUESTION:

Are both sentences correct? I'm wondering about the bolded part.

Comment: Yes, both tenses are acceptable.

Comment: They're both *syntactically* valid, but *logically / semantically*, the first version doesn't really make sense, since by the time Bob is reporting the earlier exchange to Bob, ***he's no longer in a good mood*** (interacting with John is obviously a real downer! :) We don't normally retain Present Tense when reporting a past utterance that *was* true, but isn't any longer.